# Rails and Testing against Legacy Databases

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

All,

In a bit of a technical bind.

I've built a nice little Rails app that relies on some external databases (not defined in local migrations) for augmenting core application information. I'm sitting down to write some tests and find myself struggling with the proper solution for supporting this external data.

For instance, let's say I have a 'DailyWidgetViews' model in my new/current Rails app. At the table level it looks like:

```
id, widget_id, date, views, timestamps
```

Let's say that Widgets live in distinct database. There exist facilities to work with this scenario quite well in Rails. For instance, when defining Widget, you can do something like:

```
class Widget << ActiveRecord::Base
  establish_connection("some_legacy_db_name")
  set_table_name :crazy_widget_table_name
```

Now in DailyWidgetViews I can build a nice belongs_to association and all is well.

However, what to do when it comes time to test???

Let's say I have a DailyWidgetViews resource and want to test the /index action and return the Widget association for every DailyWidgetView. What's the recommended strategy for defining and interacting with this external data? Even if I mock everything, test:unit and rspec expect to find a definition for Widget in the test database. Additionally, a few bits of caching optimization in the application also expect to find some data here (it can be empty) at application load.

Some potential options as I see them:

1. Build a separate project that consists of only migrations. These migrations have the bare minimum in them to support legacy schema. Run this project when needed to just get the schema setup. Mock everything in the tests so that we're never interacting with this database.
2. Export legacy schema and hack db:setup to load the schema into the respective test dbs before test runs. Mock everything as in #1.

I'm leaning towards option #1 but was hoping someone had dealt with this problem before. Anyone?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If I remember correctly, the `establish_connection` method is parameterized with a connection name. So, include `Rails.env` in this string as an expression (`"crazy_conn_#{Rails.env}"`) and configure your database.yml for it. In a test env, you can setup an another db, with copied structure.

Comment: Thanks Gabor - I've taken care of that just to get the project up and running. The real problem was creating the schema in that db. Was unsure how to target migrations to a given connection. You can override connection in a migration...who knew.

Comment: That's easy. Create a custom environment in database.yml and put all configurations for it. Then `rake db:create RAILS_ENV=custom && rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=custom`.

Answer (score 0):

All you really need to do to make rake db:test:prepare do the right thing is get the correct schema into the schema.rb file.

So, if you want to make *that* file right, you have a couple options - probably more, but these come to mind.

1. Just hand edit in the schema information you need. I wouldn't recommend this, since this file will get changed if you ever need to run migrations from scratch in dev/prod.
2. Create migrations that setup the tables you need to exist and then just rely on RAILS_ENV in your environment and Rails.env in your application to take care of pointing it at the correct database.